# Your Xcode project requires migration

Tags: xcode, flutter

My project ios build fails after Xcode updating to 11.4.
steps from the manual (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration) have already been made by flutter automatically(?) - everything written there has been done.

```
MacBook-Pro-ddd:my_awesome_project dm$ flutter clean
Cleaning Xcode workspace...                                         2,9s
Deleting build...                                                    1ms
Deleting .dart_tool...                                               2ms
Deleting Generated.xcconfig...                                       0ms
Deleting flutter_export_environment.sh...                            0ms
Deleting App.framework...                                            3ms
MacBook-Pro-ddd:my_awesome_project dm$ flutter build ios
Building ru.ddd.awesomeProject for device (ios-release)...
Your Xcode project requires migration. See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration for details.
MacBook-Pro-ddd:my_awesome_project dm$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale ru-RU)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
MacBook-Pro-ddd:my_awesome_project dm$
```

Comment: ensure you have removed from pod file the line that guidelines suggests. Also check in Xcode under folder Frameworks and delete any App.Framework

Answer (score 1):

After following the official guides, Like @iluvatar_GR suggests delete `App.Framework` in addition also delete `Flutter.framework` from the `Frameworks` directory.

[image: Delete both App.Framework & Flutter.framework]

Run `flutter clean` and try running.

If there are any other errors other than `project requires migration` you might want to run `rm -rf ios/Pods` and try again.